# OpenAPI or swagger.json auto discovery

Tags: api, swagger, discovery, openapi

Is there any spec or convention on URL where one should place `swagger.json` (or whatever name it is agreed) so that public API of my site can be automatically discovered?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would suggest you to submit your suggestion via https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues as the convention will be useful to the OpenAPI/Swagger ecosystem.

Comment: @wing328, done - https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/864

Answer (score 7):

**Updated 19 April 2017:** The OpenAPI Wiki answer I gave previously is ["for a very very very old version of the spec"](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/864#issuecomment-274111635). The same source states that for 2.0 the standard is `swagger.json`, for 3.0 it changes to `openapi.json`.

Original answer:

> The OpenAPI Wiki [recommends](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/wiki#server) using an `/api-docs` endpoint, at
>   least for server APIs. I've seen several sites in the wild that use
>   that, and it's our shop standard.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Thanks. I stand corrected; will edit the answer.

Comment: Looks good now. =) But.. it still doesn't give the answer, **where** should one put those files and know where to read them from?

Answer (score 2):

How about serving the Swagger JSON in an HTTP response body, in response to an OPTIONS request for the URL / ?

This is specifically permitted by the [relevant RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7).

Further, consider implementing HATEOAS, as [strongly advocated by Roy Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

Answer (score 2):

Okay. OpenAPI 3.0 still lacking auto-discovery mechanism, I try to propose a scheme based on [some things](https://github.com/zalando/restful-api-guidelines/pull/277/files) that were already working:

1. `https://example.com/.well-known/schema-discovery` is a JSON document pointing to **array** of available schemas:

   ```
   [
     {
       "schema_url": "/openapi.json",
       "schema_type": "openapi-3.0"
     },
     {
       "schema_url": "/v2/openapi.json",
       "schema_type": "openapi-3.0"
     }
   ]
   ```
2. If there is only one version of API, then `https://example.com/openapi.json` should be enough.
3. HTTP Headers. I remember somebody from Google proposed HTTP header for pointing to API. If you can find or remember it, please tell me.